# how to get a cookie value from javascript and set it by PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

I'm new to cookie operations

Answer (score 5):

This for Javascript:

```
  function createCookie( name,value,days) 
    {
        if ( days) 
        {
            var date = new Date( );
            date.setTime( date.getTime( )+( days*24*60*60*1000));
            var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString( );
        }
        else var expires = "";
        document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie( name) 
    {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split( ';');
        for( var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) 
        {
            var c = ca[i];
            while ( c.charAt( 0)==' ') c = c.substring( 1,c.length);
            if ( c.indexOf( nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring( nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie( name) 
    {
        createCookie( name,"",-1);
    }
```

And this for php, [setcookie](http://il.php.net/setcookie)

Answer (score 1):

Reading a cookie in PHP is also easy:

$cookie_value = $_COOKIE['cookie_name'];

Comment: Remember to validate the cookie value before using it.

Answer (score 1):

I understand the question is **how to detect cookie feature on browser and server side?** and **how to set and read a cookie on both side?**

So here the answer goes:

## Detect the cookie availability

### In javaScript

First you detect the cookie enabled from the `navigator.cookieEnabled`. If it is `false`, then you set a cookie on `document.cookie` to make sure it doesn't work.

```
function are_cookies_enabled()
{
  var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;

  if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled)
  { 
    document.cookie="testcookie";
    cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
  }
  return (cookieEnabled);
}
```

### Server-side

You just read the environment variable to detect the cookie feature. 
Here is the php script:

```
# start session
session_start();

# create constant
define("IS_COOKIES",count($_COOKIE)? true:false);

# example of using constant
if(IS_COOKIES){
   # do something cookie related
}
```

Here is the perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

print "Content-Type: text/plain\n\n";

if( !defined( $ENV{'HTTP_COOKIE'} ) )
{
    print "You have cookies DISABLED";
}
else
{
    print "You have cookies ENABLED";    
}
```

## Get, set and update cookie on both side

### In javaScript

The proved **cross-browser** way is to use the [jquery.cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) plugin.

YOu include the script plugin:

```
<script src="/path/to/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

To create a session cookie:

```
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');
```

To read a cookie:

```
var cookie_value = $.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
```

### On server-side

PHP has native support for cookie manipulation.

To set a cookie through `setcookie` function, make sure you start the `sesssion` before using it:

```
session_start();
setcookie('the_cookie','value');
```

To get a cookie through `$_COOKIE` variable

```
$some_cookie = $_COOKIE['the_cookie'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie with php using the [`setcookie()`](http://www.php.net/setcookie) method.

And as for retrieving the cookie value via javascript see W3 Schools tutorial on Javascript Cookie manipulation.